# Bootstrap css float right on some divs are not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was attempting to float right a few items in a row

I want layout to look like this, even with reducing the browser size
[image]

Essentially this image layout is a bit different, but it shows a Create new User and Actions, so Action is like my "Manage bulk users"

**I just want the items to align or float to the right, so that if the browser size is reduced it is not easily stacking on top of each other**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Choose your preferred criteria values and click Search
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 margin-top-bottom-8">

      <div class="col-md-6 float-right">
        <img src="assets/images/addIcon.svg" (click)="createNewUser()" />
        <span (click)="createNewUser()">Create New User</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 float-right">
        <img src="assets/images/bulkUploadIcon.svg" (click)="openEditPopup(role)" />
        <span (click)="openEditPopup(role)">Manage Bulk Users</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is a fiddle of my code pasted below

https://jsfiddle.net/03vxqed9/

Answer (score 0):

Use `col-xs-6` that mean all sizes(from smallest to biggest)
and use `pull-right`/ `pull-left` instead `float`
**`float` does NOT work with `flex`(`row` is flexable)**

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4  pull-left">
      Choose your preferred criteria values and click Search
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8 margin-top-bottom-8  pull-right">

      <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right">
        <img src="assets/images/addIcon.svg" (click)="createNewUser()" />
        <span (click)="createNewUser()">Create New User</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right">
        <img src="assets/images/bulkUploadIcon.svg" (click)="openEditPopup(role)" />
        <span (click)="openEditPopup(role)">Manage Bulk Users</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use pull-left and pull-right instead of float. See snippet bellow.

use a clearfix class to reset the floated elements.

Hope this will work for you!

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 pull-left">
      Choose your preferred criteria values and click Search
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 margin-top-bottom-8 pull-right">

      <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
        <img src="assets/images/addIcon.svg" (click)="createNewUser()" />
        <span (click)="createNewUser()">Create New User</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
        <img src="assets/images/bulkUploadIcon.svg" (click)="openEditPopup(role)" />
        <span (click)="openEditPopup(role)">Manage Bulk Users</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row top-bar">
    <div class="col-md-6 panel-left"> 
        Choose your preferred criteria values and click Search 
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 panel-right">
      <div class="col-md-8 pull-right"> 
        <img class="iconx" src="assets/images/addIcon.svg" onClick="createNewUser()" /> 
        <span onClick="createNewUser()">Create New User</span> 
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 pull-right"> 
        <img class="iconx" src="assets/images/bulkUploadIcon.svg" onClick="openEditPopup(role)" /> 
        <span onClick="openEditPopup(role)">Manage Bulk Users</span> 
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**STYLES**

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.top-bar {
  display:flex;width:100%;
}
.panel-right { display:flex;}
.iconx { clear:right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 pull-left">
      Choose your preferred criteria values and click Search
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
                <img src="assets/images/addIcon.svg" (click)="createNewUser()" />
                <span (click)="createNewUser()">Create New User</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
                <img src="assets/images/bulkUploadIcon.svg" (click)="openEditPopup(role)" />
                <span (click)="openEditPopup(role)">Manage Bulk Users</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```